# run two tests with Gradle through the command line

Tags: testing, gradle

How do I run two or more, not all, tests in Gradle through the command line?

I know that I can run a single test with `--test MyTestClassName`.

Kind of `--test TestA,TestB` looks to work, but it doesn't:  No tests found for given includes: [TestA,TestB]

Is it even possible? I mean, my IDE is able to, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like: --test TestA --test TestB